# How to cache NSUrlSession response data

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlcache

I know that this question is ask many time, but all those are not solved my problem. I want to cache Webservice Data which I getting in from a URl. If cached data available then load data from the cache and with that in background thread it also checks if data is changed then cache update and data load with new data.
I tried following code but nothing work.

```
-(void)getcountrylist
{
    [self setSharedCacheForImages];

    NSString *urlString = @"https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all";

    NSURLSession *session = [self prepareSessionForRequest];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSArray *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

               NSLog(@"Result new = %@",jsonResponse);

            });
        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}

- (NSURLSession *)prepareSessionForRequest
{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    [sessionConfiguration setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"Content-Type": @"application/json", @"Accept": @"application/json"}];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

    return session;
}

- (void)setSharedCacheForImages
{
    NSUInteger cashSize = 250 * 1024 * 1024;
    NSUInteger cashDiskSize = 250 * 1024 * 1024;
    NSURLCache *imageCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cashSize diskCapacity:cashDiskSize diskPath:@"https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all"];

    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:imageCache];   
}
```

Comment: there are many method to handle cache data using `NSMutableURLRequest`, you can check.

Comment: @vaibhav can you give me some idea or method name.

Comment: check my ans and let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle cache data using `NSMutableURLRequest` class `setCachePolicy` method. There are many methods works accordingly have a look.

**NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData:** This methods ignores cache data and fetch the fresh updated response from server.

Specifies that the data for the URL load should be loaded from the originating source. No existing cache data should be used to satisfy a URL load request.

**NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy:** Specifies that the caching logic defined in the protocol implementation, if any, is used for a particular URL load request. This is the default policy for URL load requests.

**NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData:** Specifies that not only should the local cache data be ignored, but that proxies and other intermediates should be instructed to disregard their caches so far as the protocol allows.

**Some more check here:** [source](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlrequest.cachepolicy).

Uses:

```
NSURLRequest *Request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLForService_Providers] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];
```

OR

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData];
```

Comment: I added this policy
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad;

but I am not able to cache data.Can you please tell me how to check data is coming from cache or not.

Comment: if you dont use and `cachePolicy` method by default you are loading data from cache.

Comment: I also tried with  request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad;but nothing data showing,means cache not working

Comment: No, there is age of data expiration over cache when you use this method it returned data if exists but no attempt is made to load the data from the originating source(means your server).

Comment: can we load data in offline mode.I found this "NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad".but it's not working.

Comment: yes, but before that you can search for the data expiration age.

Comment: I have seted timeoutInterval:60.0 but in offline it's not working

Comment: this doesn't sets the age of data existence, it sets the receiver’s timeout interval. [look](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest/1414063-timeoutinterval).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134190/discussion-between-yatendra-and-vaibhav).

Comment: please come on chat